# Can't install nvidia-3xx, missing requirements lib32gcc1 and libc6-i386

Tags: apt, nvidia

Missing requirements lib32gcc1 and libc6-i386. Installing lib32gcc1 says I need libc6-i386. libc6-i386 says I need libc6 (= 2.19-10ubuntu2.1), but libc6 is already installed.

Comment: How do you know that `libc6` is already installed? Maybe you could post the output of `apt-get` or whichever package manager you're using?

Comment: @YiJiang It's in Dutch and I don't know how to change it to English, but apt tells me I'm missing the dependencies lib32gcc1 and libc6-i386. I know I have libc6 installed because when I download it with apt it tells me I have already installed it.

Answer (score 0):

A few immediate ideas that I can see based on your question and the comments:

1. You've got a different version of libc6 installed than 2.19-10ubuntu2.1, which is the specific version your question indicates you need.
2. Assuming you've installed Ubuntu on modern hardware, you probably have the 64 bit version of libc6 installed and this is looking for the 32 bit version.
3. The server you're connecting trying to pull the updates down from doesn't have everything you need on it. Trying going into Software & Updates app, switch the "Download from" option to "Main server", update your repos, and try again.